# Printf() mostrando caracteres estranhos

Tags: c, string, printf, substring

O objetivo do código é mostrar todas as sub-strings da variável `firstString` que tem o mesmo tamanho da segunda string que é a variável `secondString`.
No entanto, quando uso o `printf("%s\n", pieceOfFirstString);` mostra que a string tem alguns caracteres estranho, e eu não sei de onde esses caracteres estão vindo (que interfere em outra lógica do programa), já li e reli o código várias vezes, provavelmente é algo que eu não entendo ainda.
**Os casos excepcionais como, segunda string maior que a primeira e strings de mesmo tamanho foram cobertos no código original, esse é um exemplo mínimo verificável.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int STRING_MAX_SIZE = 100;

int main()
{
    char firstString[STRING_MAX_SIZE];
    char secondString[STRING_MAX_SIZE];
    scanf("%s\n%s", firstString, secondString);

    int sizeFirstString = strlen(firstString);
    int sizeSecondString = strlen(secondString);

    char pieceOfFirstString[sizeSecondString];
    for (int firstCharIndex = 0; sizeFirstString - firstCharIndex >= sizeSecondString; firstCharIndex++)
        for (int lastCharIndex = firstCharIndex + 1; lastCharIndex - firstCharIndex != sizeSecondString; lastCharIndex++)
        {
            int sizeOfPiece = (lastCharIndex - firstCharIndex) + 1;

            if (sizeOfPiece == sizeSecondString)
            {
                strncpy(pieceOfFirstString, firstString + firstCharIndex, sizeOfPiece);
                
                printf("%s\n", pieceOfFirstString);
            }
        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Um pedaço de código diferente que eu usei e deu certo foi utilizar `argc` e `argv` para ler as strings:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* firstString = argv[1];
    char* secondString = argv[2];

    int sizeFirstString = strlen(firstString);
    int sizeSecondString = strlen(secondString);

    // (...) Continua lógica do outro pedaço de código.
}
```

Porem eu quero que o código funcione usando `scanf();`.

Um exemplo de input para testar o código `firstString`, `secondString`, nessa ordem, e as saídas, atual (com erro), ideal (sem nenhum tipo de erro).
*Input (Exemplo):*

```
abababa
ab
```

*Output (Atual):*
Usando o `scanf();` para ler as variáveis.

```
ab▒▒b
ba▒▒b
ab▒▒b
ba▒▒b
ab▒▒b
ba▒▒b
```

*Output (Ideal):*
Usando o `argc` e `argv` para ler as variáveis.

```
ab
ba
ab
ba
ab
ba
```

*Resumo do problema: Eu não sei porque o resultado do algoritmo muda com o tipo de leitura das variáveis `firstString` e `secondString`, e o que eu preciso é que o resultado do algoritmo usando a leitura com `scanf();` seja a mesma que o resultado da leitura com `argc` e `argv`.*

Comment: Podia definir melhor o que está tentando fazer? O que são substrings de uma string? Permutações de qualquer tamanho? Ou se refere a ocorrências da segunda string na primeira? De que modo?  O que seria? Não entendi o exemplo e nem o lance do argc/argv. Que tem os parâmetros de execução a ver com sub-strings? Seria outra maneira de introduzir 2 strings para o programa? O que muda no programa?

Comment: Tentei definir melhor, espero que agora de pra entender.  o argc/argv foi só uma forma diferente que eu sei para ler as variáveis, que, eu não sei porque, funcionou corretamente, enquanto usando o scanf não funciona.

Comment: Se objetivo do código é mostrar todas as sub-strings da variável `firstString` que tem o mesmo tamanho da segunda string que é a variável `secondString`, dê uma uma olhada [nesse exemplo](https://ideone.com/xhkXKX) que é uma opção bem mais simples de realizar a mesma tarefa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `strncpy` não coloca o `\0` no final da cópia quando a quantidade de caracteres a serem copiados é menor do que a string copiada.

Tente isso:

```
if (sizeOfPiece == sizeSecondString)
{
    strncpy(pieceOfFirstString, firstString + firstCharIndex, sizeOfPiece);
    pieceOfFirstString[sizeOfPiece] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", pieceOfFirstString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "O objetivo do código é mostrar todas as sub-strings da variável `firstString` que tem o mesmo **tamanho** da segunda string que é a variável `secondString`"

Para o que diz que precisa fazer basta o tamanho da segunda string, já que nada dela será usado.

Assim pode apenas determinar o tamanho dela e um ponteiro para o início da substring, e ir "flutuando" um zero pela entrada como terminador dos resultados.

#### Veja um exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char first [100];
    char second[100];
    int  res = 0;
    if (argc == 3)
    {   // aceita os argumentos se vieram dois
        strcpy(first, argv[1]);
        strcpy(second, argv[2]);
    }
    else
    {   // cancela se nao ler duas strings
        printf("Entre com as duas strings: ");
        int res = scanf("%s %s", first, second);
        if (res != 2) return -1;
    }   // if()
    size_t len = strlen(second);
    size_t n   = strlen(first) - len;
    printf(
        "\
Strings consideradas: 1: \"%s\" e \"%s\"\n\n\
substrings de \"%s\" de tamanho %zd: { ", 
        first, second, first, len );
    char save = 0;
    char* p    = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1, p+= 1)
    { 
        save = *(p + len);
        *(p + len) = 0;
        printf("\"%s\"  ", p);
        *(p + len) = save;
    }
    printf("\"%s\" }\n", p); // o ultimo
    return 0;
}
```

Nesse caso pode usar as duas opções: ou entra com as duas strings na linha de comando ou o programa pergunta depois:

```
PS> ./f0-0817
Entre com as duas strings: abababa ab
Strings consideradas: 1: "abababa" e 2: "ab"

substrings de "abababa" de tamanho 2: { "ab"  "ba"  "ab"  "ba"  "ab"  "ba"  }

PS> ./f0-0817 abababa ab
Strings consideradas: 1: "abababa" e 2: "ab"

substrings de "abababa" de tamanho 2: { "ab"  "ba"  "ab"  "ba"  "ab"  "ba"  }
```

#### Esse loop extrai os valores

```
    char save = 0;
    char* p    = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1, p+= 1)
    { 
        save = *(p + len);
        *(p + len) = 0;
        printf("\"%s\"  ", p);
        *(p + len) = save;
    }
```

É mais simples escrever assim.

#### Se não pode usar ponteiros em C

Sem ponteiros é claro a mesma coisa, só é mais difícil de ler e precisa de um loop a mais porque não pode passar o novo endereço inicial para `printf()`. **Porque**? Porque seria claro um `char*`.
Em C vetores são base + deslocamento. Então esse código faz a mesma coisa do exemplo acima, mas sem os ponteiros:

```
    char  save = 0;
    size_t  ix = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i += 1, ix += 1)
    {
        save       = first[ix+len];
        first[ix+len] = 0;
        printf("\"");
        for (size_t j = ix; j<ix+len; j += 1)
            printf("%c ", first[j]);
        printf("\" ");
        first[ix+len] = save;
    }
    printf("}\n");  // o ultimo
```

#### Saída desse caso, usando seus dados

Se entrar com dois parâmetros o programa usa esses dois

```
PS> ./f1-0817
Entre com as duas strings: abababa ab
Strings consideradas: 1: "abababa" e 2: "ab"

substrings de "abababa" de tamanho 2: { "ab" "ba" "ab" "ba" "ab" "ba" }

PS> ./f1-0817 abababa ab
Strings consideradas: 1: "abababa" e 2: "ab"

substrings de "abababa" de tamanho 2: { "ab" "ba" "ab" "ba" "ab" "ba" }
```

#### O programa completo, o que não usa ponteiros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char first[100];
    char second[100];
    int  res = 0;
    if (argc == 3)
    {  // aceita os argumentos se vieram dois
        strcpy(first, argv[1]);
        strcpy(second, argv[2]);
    }
    else
    {  // cancela se nao ler duas strings
        printf("Entre com as duas strings: ");
        int res = scanf("%s %s", first, second);
        if (res != 2) return -1;
    }  // if()
    size_t len = strlen(second);
    size_t n   = strlen(first) - len;
    printf(
        "\
Strings consideradas: 1: \"%s\" e \"%s\"\n\n\
substrings de \"%s\" de tamanho %zd: { ",
        first, second, first, len);
    char  save = 0;
    size_t  ix = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i += 1, ix += 1)
    {
        save       = first[ix+len];
        first[ix+len] = 0;
        printf("\"");
        for (size_t j = ix; j<ix+len; j += 1) printf("%c ", first[j]);
        printf("\" ");
        first[ix+len] = save;
    }
    printf("}\n");  // o ultimo
    return 0;
}
```

Se precisa procurar algo na primeira baseado na segunda string acho que em geral o mais simples é usar uma máquina de estados.

#### Sobre o seu programa

```
const int STRING_MAX_SIZE = 100;

int main()
{
    char firstString[STRING_MAX_SIZE];
```

Não pode declarar isso assim, pelo padrão. o tamanho do vetor tem que ser conhecido em tempo de compilação.

```
    scanf("%s\n%s", firstString, secondString);
```

Considere ajudar quem vai usar o programa explicando o que é para ele fazer com o cursor ali parado esperando duas strings.

E teste SEMPRE o retorno de `scanf()`. Qual o sentido se seguir o programa se não ler as duas strings?

```
    for (int firstCharIndex = 0;
         sizeFirstString - firstCharIndex >= sizeSecondString;
         firstCharIndex++)
        for (int lastCharIndex = firstCharIndex + 1;
             lastCharIndex - firstCharIndex != sizeSecondString;
             lastCharIndex++)
```

Evite nomes assim tão grandes. Só fica difícil de ler.

Comment: O seu código não satisfaz como resposta pois não resolve o meu problema: "o que eu preciso é que o resultado do algoritmo usando a leitura com scanf(); seja a mesma que o resultado da leitura com argc e argv." A resposta do @Vander Santos sim resolveu, e eu não especifiquei mas não poderia usar ponteiros. Sobre o nomes da variáveis acredito que seja uma boa prática, que o código fica muito mais fácil de ler e ser entendido.

Comment: Continuo não entendendo: o programa que eu te mostrei não só dá o mesmo resultado como você pode testar em seguida, usando ou não `argc` e `argv`. No mesmo código. E não precisa copiar `PiecesOfFirstString` para lugar nenhum, Basta manipular os índices.  :) pena que não te ajudou. Se sobrar um tempo eu te mostro como fazer sem usar ponteiros. **spoiler**: é a mesma coisa. Só é mais difícil de ler sem os ponteiros. Arrays em C são só isso: base + deslocamento. Basta trocar os ponteiros pela soma.

Comment: Não poder usar ponteiros em  C é uma restrição bem estranha, e você devia mesmo ter dito que não podia usá-los. Quem ia imaginar?

Comment: Em tempos de pandemia não saio do escritório mesmo. :) coloquei um exemplo de como você pode fazer sem ponteiros, em C.